# How do I make and assign roles using discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a completly new role in discord (with discord.py) but everything I try, doesn't work. I allready tried

```
await guild.create_role(name("R3KT")) #NameError: name 'guild' not defined
```

and

```
author = ctx.message.author
await client.create_role(author.server, name="role name") #NameError: name 'ctx' not defined
```

I've tried changing ctx and guild to 'client' but it still didn't work. if needed I'll send the whole code (without the discord name and bot key)

here's the entire code:

```
import discord

token = "bot-key"
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online and connected to Discord")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    message.content = message.content.upper()

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("AS HELLO"):
        await message.channel.send("works")

    elif message.content.startswith("AS CREATEROLE"):
        if str(message.author) == "myDiscName#6969":
            author = message.author
            await discord.create_role(author.server, name="R3KT")

    elif message.content.startswith("AS GIVEROLE"):
        if str(message.author) == "myDiscName#6969":
            print("give role")


client.run(token)
```

Comment: Can you post in your entire code (including your `on_message` or command events)

Comment: here, I posted the whole code. Hope you'll be able to find any flaws. (also as I've said, I replaced the disc name and bot key)

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you provided, it looks like you're using a mish-mash between the old d.py (`0.16.x`) docs and d.py rewrite (`1.x`).

Make sure you have the most up-to-date version (rewrite) installed, as async is no longer being maintained.

Here's an example with the command decorator (usage: `!newrole Member`)

```py
@client.command()
async def newrole(ctx, *, rolename=None):
    if not rolename:
        await ctx.send("You forgot to provide a name!")
    else:
        role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name=rolename, mentionable=True)
        await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully created and assigned {role.mention}!")
```

The `mentionable` kwarg isn't compulsory - it defaults to `False` if not specified - I just set it to `True` for the example. You're also able to write your own permissions for the role.

---

And another example using `on_message` - recommended to use command decorator instead, as args are easier to deal with

```py
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[2:] # 2: because prefix contains space
    if message.content.lower().startswith("as createrole"):
        role = await message.guild.create_role(name=" ".join(args))
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send(f"Successfully created and assigned {role.mention}!")
```

---

**References:**

- [discord.py Rewrite docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
- [`Guild.create_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role)
- [`discord.Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [`discord.on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check by name and number (as you can change that if you have nitro), you should check by ID which is unique to every user and immutable.

Also note that `server` is referred to as `guild` in `discord.py`.

```py
    elif message.content.startswith("AS CREATEROLE"):
        if message.author.id == YOUR_ID_GOES_HERE: # find your id by right clicking on yourself and selecting "copy id" at the bottom of the menu of options
            author = message.author
            # create a role named "R3KT" that has the permissions "Administrator" that has the color "white" that is not displayed separately and is not mentionable by everyone
            await message.guild.create_role(name="R3KT", permissions=discord.Permissions(8), colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 255, 255), hoist=False, mentionable=False)
```

[Permissions integer calculator](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#268435624)

[`discord.Guild.create_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_role#discord.Guild.create_role)

With giving yourself a role:

```py
    elif message.content.startswith("AS GIVEROLE"):
        if message.author.id == YOUR_ID_GOES_HERE:
            user = message.author
            await user.add_roles(message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID_GOES_HERE), reason='Someone did a giverole bot command') # left click on the role and click "copy id"
```

[`discord.Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles)

[`discord.Guild.get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role)

Comment: the creating a new role part worked, Thanks! but there's an error with the assigning part.

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Member.add_roles' was never awaited
  user.add_roles(message.guild.get_role(714872502714761287), reason='test') # left click on the role and click "copy id"

Comment: Yup, good catch. `await user.add_roles(message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID_GOES_HERE), reason='test')` should work

Comment: this works. Massive thanks! The only question I have left, is, if there's a way to automaticly get the new role's ID? becuase I'm going to use this on my friend's server, on which I don't have admin perms so I can't get the role ID manually.

Comment: you can click on your friend in the member list, which will show you some stuff including the roles he has. Right click the role you want to target and click copy ID

Comment: that won't work because the role will only be assigned to me and no one else. I want the bot to make the role on my command and assign that role to me on another command (only I will be able to execute those 2 commands). But when I make the role with the first command it gets a uniqe ID that it needs for the 2nd command.

Comment: Try [`discord.Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Guild.roles). It gives a list of `discord.Role` objects, which include the name, ID, and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.if you use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62025695/15117453) in V2.11 of discord.py lib your bot crate new role even you created this role before. with this code you can see list of all roles that you have in server and you can pick the role you want and assign to user:

```
    async def add_role(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member, rolename: discord.Role):
        if not rolename:
            await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.mention}\ndon't forget to provide a name!")
        else:
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f"Successfully created and assigned `{role.name}` to {member.mention}!")
```